# Can't Upload Sketch, Atmel SDM Chip Overheating

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a chinese CH340 clone arduino. It was working fine until now. The L light stays always on. The sdm Atmel chip is overheating to the point that I can't even touch it. The card is listed under com ports however I can't upload anything due to:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Should I just throw it away or is there a way to save it?

Comment: I had a similar question, maybe it helps: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/41806/possible-reason-for-broken-uno

Comment: How was it being powered?

Comment: It's dead, Jim.

Comment: @SDsolar It was powered with a 12V adapter. It was also connected with a rfc522 module and a relay module. Apparently rfc522 also doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Remember the Software Engineer from this joke:  http://www.cs.uni.edu/~mccormic/humor.html

Comment: Here are some fun links about Arduinos on fire:  https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+on+fire

Comment: SDM... Do you mean SMD (Surface Mount Device)?